# IntelliSense: argument of type "_TCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, opencv, image-processing, char, type-conversion

Sorry for asking such a beginner question but I'm really new to openCV and VC++2010. I searched the net for an answer but I did not get an appropriate one.

Building the first project "First Program-Display a Picture" of the OReilly-LearningOpenCV book, I encountered these errors:

```
1-error C2664: 'cvLoadImage' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_TCHAR *' to 'const char *'  
2-IntelliSense: argument of type "_TCHAR *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"
```

here's the code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{   IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );
    cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
    cvShowImage( "Example1", img );
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &img );
    cvDestroyWindow( "Example1" );
     system("pause");
     return 0;
 }
```

and here's the message that I get from Microsoft Visual Studio 2010:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FirstProgram_DisplayAPicture3, Configuration: Debug x64 ------  
1>Build started 7/6/2013 11:13:00 AM.  
1>InitializeBuildStatus:  
1>  Touching "x64\Debug\FirstProgram_DisplayAPicture3.unsuccessfulbuild".  
1>ClCompile:  
1>  All outputs are up-to-date.  
1>  FirstProgram_DisplayAPicture3.cpp  
1>FirstProgram_DisplayAPicture3.cpp(9): error C2664: 'cvLoadImage' : cannot convert parameter 1 from '_TCHAR *' to 'const char *'  
1>          Types pointed to are unrelated; conversion requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast  
1>  
1>Build FAILED.  
1>  
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:00.68  
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

**Additional information that may be required:

I have made a win32 Console Application and in the second page of the wizard I have chosen precompiled header setting.

I have changed the platform of the project to x64 because I'm using win7x64 as the OS.

I have linked openCV library to my project properly.

I have just introduced highgui.lib as the additional dependencies**

Any help would be appreciated.
What can I do to solve the two errors?

**Edited section:

Note that these errors occur in line 6, I mean the line IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );**

**My edited section based on Roger Rowland's suggestion:

Based on what Roger Rowland said, I changed the Character Set property of the project to Not Set. The two errors mentioned above got solved but these errors rose up.

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol cvReleaseImage referenced in function main**

How can I solve the problem?

Comment: Your project properties evidently specify UNICODE, so either change the project properties or amend your code to use the `_T` macro around quoted strings, e.g. `cvShowImage(_T("Example1"), img );`

Comment: thanks @Roger Rowland but I tested your suggestion and tried to use _T around quoted strings. The errors increase to 5 numbers.I mean besides line 6 "IplImage* img = cvLoadImage( argv[1] );" that produced the two errors above we will have an error **IntelliSense: argument of type "const wchar_t *" is incompatible with parameter of type "const char *"** in each line that has quoted strings and I didn't understood your purpose of saying _enhance the project properties_

Comment: You need an underscore before the T, or alternatively use `TEXT("string")` instead of `_T("string")`. If you can't do that, right-click on your project in the VS2010 solution explorer panel, choose *Properties* from the menu, then under *Configuration Properties/General* find where it says *Character Set* and change this to *Not Set*.

Comment: @Roger Rowland using TEXT("string") will produce the error **IntelliSense: identifier "TEXT" is undefined** and of coarse I had used _T not just T. It was a kind of typo here but I have not tried changing the project properties yet and I will do it now.

Comment: @Roger Rowland I tried changing the project properties. It omitted the two mentioned errors but two other errors rose up. Please look at **"my edited section based on Roger Rowland's suggestion"** I will update it in just a minute.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your project is configured for Unicode which means that the `_TCHAR` macro evaluates to `wchar_t`, which is a 16 bit UTF-16 data type on Windows. But the library you are calling accepts 8 bit `char` data.

So, you will need to make both sides of the interface match. Lots of ways to do that. The obvious options are:

1. Change your project to target ANSI (change the character set to multi byte in the VS project configuration).
2. Convert the input argument from UTF-16 to ANSI before calling the library.

It seems to me to be needlessly complex to use `_TCHAR` these days. That was useful when we needed to support Win9x (no Unicode support) and WinNT (supports Unicode) from a single code base. But I expect that nowadays you are targeting NT based systems and so you are safe to assume support for Unicode. In which case you can use `wchar_t`, `wstring` etc.

On the other hand, perhaps this is just a simple program for your personal use. In which case, since your library wants 8 bit characters, maybe it's simplest for you to target ANSI.

But either way I rather suspect that `_TCHAR` is just going to confuse you. I'd abandon that if I were you.

One final point is that you mention that you target x64 since your system is 64 bit. Do be aware that 64 bit systems can run 32 bit code perfectly well. If you want your program to be capable of running on a 32 bit system, and you don't have a pressing need to run under 64 bit, then it may be easier to target x86.

---

Your edit to the question asks a separate question, which I'll attempt to answer in spite of my reservations.

The *unresolved external symbol* error indicates that the linker could not resolve that particular symbol. In order for the linker to resolve it, it needs to be passed the .lib file that defines that symbol. You should double check that you have included all required .lib files in your additional dependencies. From what I can glean, there are multiple .lib files for OpenCV and you are probably missing the one which defines `cvReleaseImage`.

Comment: I understand what you mean and tried to change the project properties based on what Roger Rowland said.Look at 'My edited section based on Roger Rowland's suggestion' Two questions rose up for me based on your answer 1-How can I change the project to target ANSI I'm absolutely new to VS and should it be besides changing the character set property of the project? 2-You now that _TCHAR is not something written by me. It's just VS's prepared code when you produce a console application precompiled header in VS and since that I'm new

Comment: Yes, I understand the VS leads you down this confusing path. I always strip it all away and use `wchar_t` or `char`. You change the character set to multi byte. That's it.

Comment: trhanks @David Heffernan How can I do your 2nd suggestion **Convert the input argument from UTF-16 to ANSI before calling the library** since I'm new to VS, I don't know what will be the risk after omitting TCHAR and how to omit? Based on my experiences in DEVC++ we didn't user TCHAR we just used char

Comment: There is no risk of omitting `_TCHAR`. To omit it, just stop using it! Change the character set to multibyte and change your main to: `int main(int argc, char* argv[])` and it's all good. The best way to convert between different character encodings is an involved topic. There's no single simple answer. We cannot really do all this in comments.

Comment: For example, perhaps you'd use the ATL macros described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87zae4a3(v=vs.110).aspx which are a good choice, but there are other options. This question is in danger of expanding into a huge debugging session. You've already got two questions for the price of one!  ;-)

Comment: thanks @Roger Rowland! I did what you said 1-changed my main to **int main(int argc, char* argv[]) and character set to multibyte** but did not change the target to ANSI and in fact I don't understand what you mean by this term. But the two latter errors remain the same and get no change!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: You need to add the missing .lib files. That's the second question that you asked. I answered that below the horizontal bar. The OpenCV library comes with multiple .lib files. You've only added one, `highgui`. You should add them all.

Comment: ANSI is a term used in Windows to refer to 8 bit character sets. It is synonymous (in Windows) with multi byte character sets. The alternative is UTF-16 known in Windows world as Unicode.

Comment: Also, why are you addressing comments to Roger?

Comment: yeah you're right I just have added highgui. But the problem is I should know which functions of the openCV library are needed to solve these problems and then add the proper .libs. Do you mean that I should add all of the .libs available in the openCV libraty?????????

Comment: Oh you're right! I'm addressing the comments to Roger. pardon me! I'm just typing so carelessly.

Comment: You've gone quiet. Is it all sorted now?

Comment: No in fact I'm searching for the .lib file containing the function cvReleaseImage(). I don't want to add all of the .libs available.It seems like a common problem with other IDEs like DEVC++,too. The book hasn't mentioned any other .lib just highgui.As soon as I find the answer I will mark the accepted answer and useful comments.

Comment: thanks for your guidance @David Heffernan. Finally it got solved. I tried to edit your answer based on my findings but it seems that this editing will only be visible to me unless it is peer viewed. thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was including a header file twice.

I modified my library to be like:

```
#ifndef MY_LIB
#define MY_LIB

// code

#endif
```