# error C3861: 'system': identifier not found

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, system, intellisense, identifier

I just started a new `win32` console application in VS 2010 and set the `Additional options` property to `precompiled header`in the upcoming wizard.

Based on [one of my previous questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500696/intellisense-argument-of-type-tchar-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type) I decided to use the following main prototype:

```
int main(int argc,  char* argv[])
```

I also changed the `Character Set` property of the project to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`.

But, the following code:

```
system("pause");
```

Will produce these two errors:

```
error C3861: 'system': identifier not found  
IntelliSense: identifier "system" is undefined
```

I had the same experience before and there was no error!
Can anyone suggest me what's wrong?

Comment: did you include <stdlib.h>?

Comment: @billz adding the code `#include "stdlib.h"` on top of the code will omit one of the errors but the error `error C3861: 'system': identifier not found` remains the same. And of course the main question is: in my previous projects producing since friday (and I can put their code here), I had the same settings and their was no error!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: In C++ you should use `#include <cstdlib>`, and `std::system`.

Comment: @Mats Petersson before using the way suggested by Cody Gray, I tried to use `using namespace std` at top of my code. I think it's the same as writing `std::system` but encountered the error `IntelliSense: name must be a namespace name` Do you know why? I have studied the [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/namespaces/) this code should not have any problem?

Comment: Any help in future about the problem described in the previous comment would be appreciated. Why writing `using namespace std` makes such error? even if you use `#include <stdlib.h>` and then write `using namespace std` the problem will not be solved?!!!    Note that in spite of what was said by @Mats Petersson we can't use `#include <cstdlib.h>` but we can use `#include <stdlib.h>` and this will solely solve the problem. No need for namespace std an this will even make the issu more complicated. Please help me why?

Comment: If you are using "stdlib.h" in C++, you are liable to problems, because it's not guaranteed to be C++ safe. You should use "cstdlib", which has is guaranteed to put the `namespace std` and `extern "C"` around the code. In practice, it may well work to do either (because a lot of ancient code uses `<stdlib.h>` in the code, and it would be bad to break this. Of course, if `<stdlib.h>` does not place the function in `namespace std`, then you would get that sort of message from intellisense.

Comment: @Mats Petersson in fact the problem is when I write `#include <cstdlib.h>` encounter the error `IntelliSense: cannot open source file "cstdlib.h"` and I think this is because that it's not added as precompiled header in the `Additional Dependencies`?

Comment: @sepideh, `cstdlib`, not `cstdlib.h`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In C++, you have to include the appropriate header file that contains the declaration of a function in order to use it, otherwise you'll get a compiler error about the identifier not being found.

In the case of the `system` function, it is defined in the `stdlib.h` header file.

So, to the top of your code file (or in your precompiled header file), add the line

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

(You use the angle brackets instead of quotation marks because `stdlib.h` is a header found in a place the build tool has been previously told about; this includes system header directories and other directories your build configuration specifically calls for.)

Aside from that, I **strongly** recommend *against* using either the Multi-Byte Character Set (all new Windows applications should support Unicode) or the `system` function,  *especially* `system("pause")`.

Comment: Angle brackets are not used because it's a system header, they're used because the header file is located in one of the directories that the preprocessor has been told to search for headers in. The system header paths are known in advance, and build options (/I for MSVC? -I for most other tools) inform the tool of additional paths to search when angle brackets have been used.

Comment: @mah That's what "system header" means. It's a header that is known to your build system.

Comment: yes however there are other (non-system header) places to use angle brackets and your statement suggests otherwise. For example, lets say I have random 3rd party library myLib to be used in my project. I would reasonably include `-I /usr/home/myname/myLib` (or /I, etc) to enable `#include <myLib.h>` to be picked up from there, yet this is not a system header.

Comment: @mah Is this like a personal soapbox for you? I don't think what I said is unclear. In your example, you're adding that directory to the locations that your build system searches for system headers. The practical difference between angle brackets and quotation marks is that the latter prioritizes headers in the current working directory. But the truth is, according to the C and C++ standards, *all* of this is implementation-dependent, so you'll need to check the documentation to be sure. I can't imagine how that's relevant to someone who doesn't even know what headers are and how to use them.

Comment: @Cody Gray thanks for your guidance. The problem is fixed but can you suggest me 1-Why I didn't have such a problem in my previous projects with the same settings and not including <stdlib.h> at top of them? 2- Why do you recommend me not to use `system("pause") 3- I thought all of new windows applications most support unicode but  [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500696/intellisense-argument-of-type-tchar-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type) David Heffernan has another idea!!

Comment: It's not a personal soap box and there's no need to be rude. I was simply trying to help _you_ to see that your statement was inappropriate because depending on how you look at it, it's either incomplete or inaccurate. Beyond that, it's not even necessary to be there in order to provide an answer to what was actually being asked.

Comment: @mah I wasn't trying to be rude. I still don't think it's either incomplete or inaccurate. As I said, those are all headers known to your build system. What is incomplete or inaccurate about that statement? Your example only proved that you can inform your build system of additional headers. I'm not disputing that.

Comment: @sepideh 1) I have no idea why it worked before. Chances are, the header was included somewhere and you just didn't see it. 2) Tons of reasons: it's slow, it's platform-dependent, it's insecure, and it's useless. Why do you need your program to pause? 3) That's not what David is suggesting. I can say with confidence that he agrees with me here: all new Windows applications should be built with Unicode support. He's just explaining why that person's code didn't work, because it was mixing `char*` and `wchar_t*` strings.

Comment: I feel it's incomplete/inaccurate because when you call something a "system header" that has a specific meaning that "known to your build system (because you told the system about it just now) goes beyond. One would expect something called a system header to always be available, no? Anyway I suppose I'm just being overly pedantic over the word "system".

Comment: @mah Perhaps. I recommend filing bug reports with both Microsoft and the GCC folks. Their documentation similarly (ab)uses the "system headers" notation. If you think you can express it better, then you can edit my answer. As for why I included it at all, it was to help clear up the inevitable confusion: "why do I sometimes see `#include` statements that use quotation marks instead of angle brackets?"

Comment: so thanks @Cody Gray but 3-If you study my problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500696/intellisense-argument-of-type-tchar-is-incompatible-with-parameter-of-type), what will you suggest to solve it? David suggested to use `int main(int argc,  char* argv[])` and changing the `Character Set' to `Use Multi-Byte Character Set`. I'm not saying that your opinion's wrong. I do like my programs support unicode (I'm a beginner) in the future and I have gotten more curious about the way?

Comment: @sepideh I don't understand what problem it is that you're trying to solve. The declaration of main is wrong, it should look like this: `int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])`, which works fine when `UNICODE` and `_UNICODE` are defined. The Visual Studio project templates set this all up for you correctly.

Comment: I really appreciate Cody Gray and mah's guidance but to be more curious `having stdlib.h in the External Dependencies part of the solution explorer( it's added when you create a win32 console application precompiled header automatically)`does not mean that we should not have such a problem?? I'm steal confused of why I didn't have the problem in my previous projects with the same settings? any help in the future would be appreciated.

Comment: found the reason why `system("pause")` didn't make problems in the previous codes: Since I'm working with the openCV library I always had `#include "highgui.h" at the top of my code and I glean that perhaps this function is supported by this header file just like `cvWaitKey` method.

Answer (score 3):

What worked for me was ensuring that the `#include "stdafx.h"` was the FIRST INCLUDE in the file.  So `#include <iostream>` would therefore be after this.

Doing this solved the issue.